# Qual tamanho devo definir para armazenar uma string base64 em um campo VARCHAR?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, base64

Preciso armazenar uma imagem que esta em base64 no banco de dados mysql...

Minhas dúvidas são:

1 - Eu devo comprimir essa string antes de salvar no banco, se sim qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

1.2 - A imagem base64 é gerada no client-side, então eu devo comprimir a string no client ou server-side...para então armazenar no banco?

2 - Será necessário eu criar uma coluna VARCHAR com o tamanho/valor máximo no mysql?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a url da imagem: https://pastecry.pt/bYwnq6#GamYmVeq%23Yh1Suh2Feq3Nup0Kew

---

No contexto geral, eu gero um gráfico utilizando a biblioteca amCharts em uma pagina e tiro um print com o html2canvas (base64).

Eu preciso armazenar essa imagem no banco dados para posteriormente trazer a imagem em um pdf quando for necessário.

Segue a página com o gráfico:
http://evolvetihost.com.br/sites/d3coaching/dev/resultado.php?nome=teste&telefone=5545376586759&email=teste1@email.com.br&estado=AL&idade=2&genero=Masculino&estado_civil=Solteiro(a)&perfeccionista=100&vitimista=100&dominador=100&ajudante=100&auto_sacrificio=100&inseguranca=100&inflexibilidade=100&postura_punitiva=100&negativismo_e_pessimismo=100&subjugacao=80

No final da pagina tem a imagem em base64 oculta, o src dela está atribuído em uma variável, a qual pretendo enviar para o banco via ajax...

Comment: Eu até tentei responder, mas as duas primeiras a resposta é: só você sabe, não temos como responder para você, não sem requisitos, se fosse para fazer sempre de um jeito já estaria pronto. Eu provavelmente usaria um `TEXT` e não `VARCHAR`. Pra falar a verdade eu não usaria Base64 para gravar, mas você pode fazer como achar melhor e atender sua necessidade.

Comment: @Maniero, no contexto geral...eu gero um grafico utilizando a biblioteca amCharts, e preciso armazenar uma print desse resultado (gráfico), para posteriormente trazer a imagem em um pdf quando for solicitado.

Comment: @Maniero, sobre as duas primeiras perguntas são referentes ao meu receio de salvar essa string base64 longa desse jeito e ter problemas com o banco futuramente...

Comment: Pega todos os gráficos que já fez e olha o maior deles, adiciona uns bits a mais para ter certeza e pronto, já tem o tamanho que precisa

Comment: @Costamilam, boa dica...criei a coluna como TEXT no banco, e ja estou salvando nela...consegui fazer o select e trazer a imagem no pdf corretamente em um tempo de carregamento aceitável.